# IDE warning in Custom views in Android

Tags: android, view

I'm really curious about constructors for custom views. Currently I have one which `extends` the `RelativeLayout`. Each view need `context` for initialization. So, I put `super()` in the constructor. Although, I need the `activity` in my class so I took `context` from it. As far as I know, `activity` is a `context` too so why `Android Studio` gives me an inspection that I am missing the constructor with `context` ? My class looks like this:

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {

    private Activity activity;

    public CustomView(Activity activity) {
        super(activity.getApplicationContext());
        this.activity = activity;
        initialize(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    //initialize method
}
```

This is the exact message `Android Studio` gives me:

*Custom view CustomView is missing constructor used by tools: (Context) or (Context,AttributeSet) or (Context,AttributeSet,int)*

Should I ignore this or should I pass in constructor both: `activity` and `context`?

Thanks for all information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better pass `Context` instead of `Activity`, because its possible to call `View` with `Context` but without `Activity`. For example if you call `Dialog` from `Service`.

Also based on [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) there is only one constructor is *really necessary*. But that constructor has contain `AttributeSet` as argument.

In your case it should looks like

```
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.activity = (Activity) context; //better to hold context actually
    initialize(context);
}
```

And for sure good practice is to use all available constructors